# How to tell how many speeds a wheel is designed for

Tags: road-bike, wheels

Let's say I have a freehub wheel with no cassette.  How do I determine how many sprockets it's designed for?  In particular, the wheel in question is a [Mavic Aksium](https://shop.mavic.com/en-us/aksium-rr0700.html).  Looking at the manufacturer's spec page, I don't see anything about number of speeds.

Comment: Are you are trying to figure out of it is compatible with an 11 speed cassette?

Comment: A recent (6-year-old +/-) Mavic Aksium is designed for 11 speed cassettes. You'll need to make sure what kind of hub is fitted, Shimano or Campagnolo. Mavic free-hub bodies can be removed and changed.

Comment: I want to use it with a 9 speed. But I really want to know the answer to this question broadly, as it applies to all wheels.

Comment: With 9 speeds you'll need specific spacers that go on the hub before the cassette is fitted.

Answer (score 4):

For Shimano and SRAM, at least:

8, 9 and 10 speed cassettes are designed to use the same freehub body. As higher speeds became available the sprockets were made closer together rather than the cassette getting wider. The freehub spline width is 34.95mm.

For road groupsets, the freehub body had to be made wider by 1.8mm (36.75mm) to accommodate 11 speed cassettes.

For mountain groupsets, the 11 speed cassette fits on the narrower 10 speed freehub. This is possible because the larger low gear sprockets on a spider can overhang the inboard end of the freehub body.

Old or cheap 7 or less speed systems use an narrower freehub body.